# How to get Particular Child nodes in Fire base android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[image: Firebase Db Structure]

i need to get bestseller values from AGS Biryani in recyler view , No idea about how to add the child values to the recyler adapter based on parent node

**Model**

```
public class Food_List {
    private String itemname;
    private String itemdescrp;
    private long itemnewprice;
    private  long itemoldprice;


    public String getItemname() {
        return itemname;
    }

    public void setItemname(String itemname) {
        this.itemname = itemname;
    }

    public String getItemdescrp() {
        return itemdescrp;
    }

    public void setItemdescrp(String itemdescrp) {
        this.itemdescrp = itemdescrp;
    }

    public long getItemnewprice() {
        return itemnewprice;
    }

    public void setItemnewprice(long itemnewprice) {
        this.itemnewprice = itemnewprice;
    }

    public long getItemoldprice() {
        return itemoldprice;
    }

    public void setItemoldprice(long itemoldprice) {
        this.itemoldprice = itemoldprice;
    }

}
```

**Food_List_ViewHolders**

ViewHolders to add the value in Recyler view

```
public class Food_List_ViewHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    private Context context;
    Context mContext;
    String nodata;
    public Food_List_ViewHolders(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        mView=itemView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    public  void setDetails(Context applicationContext, final String itemname, String itemdescrp,

                            final long itemnewprice,
                            final long itemoldprice
                            )

    {

        final TextView dishitemname=mView.findViewById(R.id.dishheader);
        TextView dishitemnamedescrp=mView.findViewById(R.id.dishheaderdescrp);
        TextView dishitemnameoldprice=mView.findViewById(R.id.itemoldprice);
        TextView dishitemnamenewprice=mView.findViewById(R.id.itemnewprice);
        dishitemname.setText(itemname);
        dishitemnamedescrp.setText(itemdescrp);
        dishitemnamenewprice.setText(applicationContext.getString(R.string.Rup) +  itemnewprice);
        dishitemnameoldprice.setText(applicationContext.getString(R.string.Rup) +  itemoldprice);


        mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View mView) {

                Context context = mView.getContext();
            }

        });

    }


}
```

**Main Activity**

**Don't Know how to add Child values in DataSnapshot**

```
mRecycleriew =findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_views);
        mRecycleriew.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mFirebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("restaurants").equalTo("AGS Biryani");
        //DatabaseReference restaurantsRef =  mRef.child("restaurants");
        mRef(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                progressDoalog.dismiss();

            }

        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




    }

    private void mRef(ValueEventListener valueEventListener) {
    }


    protected void onStart() {

        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food_List,Food_List_ViewHolders> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food_List, Food_List_ViewHolders>(
                        Food_List.class,
                        R.layout.item_child,
                        Food_List_ViewHolders.class,
                        mRef)
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(Food_List_ViewHolders viewHolder, Food_List model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getItemname(),model.getItemdescrp(),model.getItemnewprice(),model.getItemoldprice());

                    }


                };

        mRecycleriew.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: You can't add to shapshot. you can only get from snapshop. if you need to send values to fire base you can use .setValue() to a node.

Comment: you can iterate snapshot to get all child under current child. using for loop e.g.  for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String name = (String) messageSnapshot.child("item").getValue();
            String price= (String) messageSnapshot.child("price").getValue();
        }

Comment: Thanks @JawadZeb Can u able to share  code ???

Comment: I will rewrite your code . tell me what you want to do? you want to get all values under resturant node?

Comment: @JawadZeb It looks like Kali is using FirebaseUI's `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, which already handles the loop you mention. His `populateViewHolder` has a model item `Food_List`, which FirebaseUI automatically deserializes from the `DataSnapshot`. I'm not (yet) sure why it's not working, but they shouldn't need to loop over `getChildren()` themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jawad not all values...i need to show "bestsellers" values from "AGS Biryani"

Comment: Thanks for reply @FrankvanPuffelen any idea  to Show "bestsellers" values in recylerview ?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you're doing:

```
mRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("restaurants").equalTo("AGS Biryani");
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food_List,Food_List_ViewHolders> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food_List, Food_List_ViewHolders>(
                    Food_List.class,
                    R.layout.item_child,
                    Food_List_ViewHolders.class,
                    mRef)
```

Which means that you're showing all restaurants with a priority of `AGS Biryani`. That's not what you're trying to do, so you'll need to modify your ref:

```
mRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("restaurants/AGS Biryani/bestsellers");
```

When you pass this ref into the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`, it will show all bestsellers for AGS Biryani.

Comment: ERROR : E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout  @Frank

Comment: That sounds like a different problem. Did you check [previous questions with that error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firebaseui+E%2FRecyclerView%3A+No+adapter+attached%3B+skipping+layout)?

Comment: mRef=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("restaurants") in this mode the layout will show,  and in this mode child("restaurants/AGS Biryani/bestsellers") layout screen is empty. i think the problem is Getter and Setter ? @Frank

Comment: how to check Fire base values("restaurants/AGS Biryani/bestsellers") in logat ? @Frank

Comment: What does your screen show when you use `/restaurants`? It seems unlikely that is correct. The `Food_List` class doesn't model a restaurant, it models a food item, which seems to be under `bestsellers`. So that's what you should point your adapter to. In my snippet that's `/restaurants/AGS Biryani/bestsellers`.